# SQL pivot query error: Dynamic company names. Error - Unclosed quotation mark

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table called Xref. 
Made up of columns `ShaftecNo, CompNo, CompName`.

[image: Xref Table]

I am trying to write a pivot query that displays `[ShaftecNo],[CompNo]` and then `[CompName]` as columns). Resulting in the following format

[image: New Pivot Table From Xrefs]

Code used in my stored procedure is as follows.

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max);
-- generate the column names
select @sql = coalesce(@sql + ',', '') + QuoteName([CompName])
from (select DISTINCT CompName from [Xrefs] WHERE CompName LIKE '[a-z]%') T;
-- replace the column names into the generic PIVOT form
set @sql = REPLACE('
select ShaftecNo, :columns:
from (SELECT ShaftecNo,CompNo,CompName FROM Xrefs INNER JOIN Product ON Xrefs.ShaftecNo COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS = Product.KeyCode) p 
pivot (max(CompNo) for CompName in (:columns:)) as pv',
':columns:', @sql)
-- execute for the results
exec (@sql)
```

Please note, the LIKE command used will work if i change it to [a-c] ( only [CompName]'s that starts with a-c range) if i do a larger range like [a-r] it errors.

> Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
>   Unclosed quotation mark after the character string 'ALFAROME'.
>   Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
>   Incorrect syntax near 'ALFAROME'.

The errors change for different ranges. If i take the like out completely the the query works BUT it misses out company names (i.e .Brake Engineering).

Can anyone help

Comment: can you print the @sql value, or does it error on that line? Put a `PRINT @SQL` in before the `exec (@sql)` for starters. Note that this particular maintenance issue is going to plague you always. Dynamic SQL is a pain. Normally you implement a crosstab in the 'reporting layer'

Comment: Check the data in your table. Do they contain quotation? I think so.

Comment: Still having a problem. Using the print @sql i can see that the sql code procdured is in-correct. It custs of at the end for some unknown reason. e.g

Comment: [FORD],[PUROLATOR],[IMASAF],[GE],[FE

Comment: The sql is therefore in-complete. changes where it cuts of when you change the like statement.

Comment: Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Unclosed quotation mark after the character string 'FE'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near 'FE'.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your `CompName` field has values that have contain single quotes, so you will need to remove/replace them when building your `@sql` value:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max);
-- generate the column names
select @sql = coalesce(@sql + ',', '') + QuoteName(replace([CompName],'''',''))
from (select DISTINCT CompName from [Xrefs] WHERE CompName LIKE '[a-z]%') T;
-- replace the column names into the generic PIVOT form
set @sql = REPLACE('
select ShaftecNo, :columns:
from (SELECT CompNo,replace(CompName,'''''''','''') as CompName FROM a INNER JOIN Product ON Xrefs.ShaftecNo COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS = Product.KeyCode) p 
pivot (max(CompNo) for CompName in (:columns:)) as pv',
':columns:', @sql)
-- execute for the results
exec (@sql)
```

Comment: Thanks for all your help. The PRINT @SQL command worked like a dream. The problem was a random unicode ascii character - 160. Which i had to get by using ...  SELECT distinct Compname, ASCII(SUBSTRING(Compname,LEN(Compname)-1,LEN(Compname))) from [Xrefs_Temp]. Then i replaced it and it worked. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your help. The PRINT @SQL command worked like a dream. (Thank you Nick.McDermaid) .

The problem was a random unicode ascii character - 160. Which i had to get by using ...

SELECT distinct Compname, ASCII(SUBSTRING(Compname,LEN(Compname)-1,LEN(Compname))) from [Xrefs_Temp].

Then i replaced it with blanks and it worked.

Thanks again

Comment: Until the next random ascii character appears! Consider doing this in the 'reporting layer' instead.